# Verify the integral $\int_1^z \frac{1}{\frac{u}{1 + \sqrt{u^2 + 1}}-u} \,du$

Tags: integration, logarithms, solution-verification, substitution

I'm stuck solving the integral

$$\int_1^z \frac{1}{\frac{u}{1 + \sqrt{u^2 + 1}}-u} \,du$$

This is what I got so far

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^z \frac{1}{\frac{u}{1 + \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} - u} \,du &= \int_{1}^z \frac{1 + \sqrt{u^2 + 1}}{u - u\cdot(1 + \sqrt{u^2 + 1})} \,du \\
 &= \int_{1}^z \frac{1 + \sqrt{u^2 + 1}}{-u\cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du = -\bigg( \underbrace{\int_1^z \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du}_{(*)} + \int_1^z \frac{1}{u}\,du\bigg) \\
 &= - (*) - \ln(z)
\end{align}

Calculation of $(*)$ yields

\begin{align*}
 (*) &= \int_1^z \frac{1}{u \cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du = \int_1^z \frac{u}{u^2  \cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du = \int_1^z \frac{\varphi'(u)}{\varphi(u)^2 - 1} \,du = \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}} \frac{1}{u^2 -1} \,du \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}} \frac{1}{u-1} \,du - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}} \frac{1}{u+1} \,du = \frac{1}{2} \bigg[\ln(u-1) - \ln(u+1)\bigg]_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(\frac{\sqrt{z^2 + 1} - 1}{\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 1}) - \ln(\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} + 1})\right)
\end{align*}

Thus we have the result

\begin{align*}
 &-\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(\frac{\sqrt{z^2 + 1} - 1}{\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 1}) - \ln(\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2} + 1})\right) - \ln(z) \\
 &= -\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(\frac{(\sqrt{z^2 + 1} - 1)^2}{(\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 1) \cdot (\sqrt{z^2 + 1} - 1)}) - \ln(\frac{(\sqrt{2} - 1)^2}{(\sqrt{2} + 1)\cdot(\sqrt{2} - 1)})\right) - \ln(z) \\
 &= -\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(\frac{z^2 + 1 - 2\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 1}{z^2}) - \ln(\frac{2 - 2\sqrt{2} + 1}{2 - 1})\right) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(z^2) \\
 &= -\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(z^2 - 2\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 2) - \ln(3 + 2\sqrt{2})\right) \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \ln(3 + 2\sqrt{2}) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(z^2 - 2\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 2)
\end{align*}

The correct solution is given by

$$\ln(\frac{\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 1}{z^2(1 + \sqrt{2})})$$

I'm not able to simplify my solution to the given solution. Did I integrate wrong or is there a way to verify the solution?

**Edit**: I think, that I made an mistake somewhere, since the solution should equal zero for $z = 1$ but $1$ is not root of my solution..

**Edit 2**: I found the mistake. I switched "+" and "-" in the line of the second last equality. My question remains how to simplify my solution to the given solution.. My solution then looks like this

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(z^2 - 2\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 2)$$

Comment: the first line in computing (*), what is $\varphi(u)$

Comment: @gt6989b It's the substitution $\varphi(u) = \sqrt{u^2 + 1}$. I already found my mistake (see the edit) but can't simplify correctly.

Comment: Simply rationalize and use properties of logarithms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(z^2 - 2\sqrt{z^2 + 1} + 2)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}{ln(\sqrt{2}-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2}{ln(\sqrt{z^2+1}-1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}({ln \frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)^2}{(\sqrt{z^2+1}-1)^2})}$$

$$={ln \frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)}{(\sqrt{z^2+1}-1)}}$$

$$={ln \frac{(\sqrt{z^2+1}+1)}{z^2(\sqrt{2}+1)}}$$

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3):

HINT: (comment)

Substitution $ u= \sinh x $ makes it easy as it gives three log terms.

$$ \int \dfrac{-(1+\cosh x)dx}{\sinh x} $$

Comment: I intentionally didn't use hyperbolic functions and already found my mistake (see edit). Now I just want to simplify to the correct solution.

Comment: at least the hyperbolic solution can be used to verify it.